# What really happens when matter and antimatter combine?

Tags: mass-energy, antimatter, matter

When Energy is converted to matter, we know equal amounts of matter and antimatter are produced. What happens when matter and antimatter combine?

Answer (score 1):

When matter and antimatter combine they produce two gamma rays with energy equal to their mass.[image]

Comment: What property causes them to anihilate? Lets say a a quark and a anti quark colide, they anihilate due to some "Dirac vacuum" effect?  Or is it solely due to spin/charge simmetry?